# Python Transfering files to and from the remote machine

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko

**i want to transfer a file local to server machine.**

```
import os

import paramiko

local_path = "/home/e100075/python/ss.txt"

remote_path = "/home/developers/screenshots/"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('hostname', username="username", password="password")

ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls /tmp')

print "output", ssh_stdout.read() 

#Reading output of the executed command

error = ssh_stderr.read()

#Reading the error stream of the executed command

print "err", error, len(error)

#Transfering files to and from the remote machine

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)

sftp.put(local_path, remote_path)

sftp.close()

ssh.close()
```

**After run the program. I got the errors below**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "file_copy.py", line 21, in <module>

    sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 606, in get

    fr = self.file(remotepath, 'rb')

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 245, in open

    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 635, in _request

    return self._read_response(num)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 682, in 
_read_response

    self._convert_status(msg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 708, in 
_convert_status

    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file
```

If you know the answer. please let me know.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a file to the server you probably will need

```
sftp.put(local_path, remote_path)
```

not

```
sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give file name also, otherwise it will throw errors

sftp.put('filename.txt','/home/user/performance/destination.txt')

where 'filename.txt' must be in current directory or else give full path